# How to Redirect the request to a special API in Serlvet؟

Tags: java, servlets

I want the processing to be directed to a specific root in a servlet corresponding to the url .What should I do؟
In this code I do a process and then I want it to be directed to the same url .

```
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // process ...
        response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI());
    }
```

But this code apparently redirects to a page .While I want it to be directed to a url !!
What should I do ؟؟؟

I wanted a certain path to run but this error is displayed:
**this page is not working localhost redirected you too many times.**

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "But this code apparently redirects to a page"? It looks to me like your current code is just responding to a request by sending a redirect *to the same URI* - so I'm not surprised you're getting the error you're getting. When do you expect the redirection loop to stop, if you're just redirecting to the same thing every time?

Comment: Can you provide more details to your question and some piece of exact code too ?

Comment: Do you  mean a *special API* is the same url you used by the get request?